# after(:create) in FactoryGirl trait

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I am using traits to modify the behavior of my factory.
When the `:with_answers` trait is used, I want to create a `quiz_answer` with the created submission as parameter.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
   factory :quiz_submission do
      quiz_id           1
      [...]

      trait :with_answers do
          after(:create) do |submission|
              FactoryGirl.create(:quiz_answer, quiz_submission: submission.id)
              [...]
          end
      end
    end
 end
```

The block that is passed to `after(:create)` is never entered, though.
Can anyone tell me why?

EDIT:
I call the factory with `FactoryGirl.create :quiz_submission, :with_answers`

Comment: `factory :quiz_submission_with_answers, traits: [: with_answers]` ... this line is missing in your post but is it in your code?

Comment: Oh I forgot the call, I added it in the post.

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution is to have a transient attribute and a global `after(:create)` handler that does the work based on that attribute.

Something like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
   factory :quiz_submission do
      transient do
        submissions_count { 0 }
      end
  
      quiz_id           1
      [...]

      trait :with_answers do
        submissions_count { 1 }
      end
 
      after(:create) do |submission, evaluator|
        create_list(:quiz_answer, evaluator.submissions_count, quiz_submission: submission.id)
        [...]
      end
    end
 end
```